# How to apply image processing in shape file or raster

Tags: python, matlab, arcgis

I wish to use matlab or python to do some image processing to ArcGIS files.
 My goal is to process the shape file or raster like normal image. We can get anypart of it and process it with any image algorithm. Then add coordinates information to show in ArcGIS. 
I searched the web and found there is a way to do it. We can use tif image in matlab. But it is too big for matlab to process even I cut the tif using a small area in ArcGIS. Please see the code and link of it.
Is there a way to do it effectively and easily? Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thank you.

```html
clc;close all;clear;
%below is using matlab blockproc to read a large file,but I failed to read a tiff
% src_filename='F:/1.tif';
% fun = @(block_struct) block_struct.data;
% B = blockproc(src_filename,[5 5],fun);
% 
% %----------below is how to do transform the coordinates----------------------------------------------------------------
% code from:http://www.cnblogs.com/denny402/p/4684770.html

[pic,R]=geotiffread('F:/lenoir/Lidar2007/1.tif');
[m,n,~]=size(pic);


figure(1),imshow(pic)
hold on; scatter(n/4,m/4,500,'r.');  
[lon,lat]=pix2map(R,m/4,n/4)
figure(2),mapshow(pic,R);
mapshow(lon,lat,'Marker','.','MarkerEdgeColor','r');

axis off;

disp(['(',num2str(m/4),',',num2str(n/4),') -> (',num2str(lon),',',num2str(lat),')']); 

%R.RasterWidthInWorld
x=R.XLimWorld(1)+(3/4)*R.RasterWidthInWorld;  
y=R.YLimWorld(1)+(1/4)*R.RasterHeightInWorld;
figure(3),mapshow(pic,R),axis off;
mapshow(x,y,'Marker','*','MarkerEdgeColor','r');
[row,col]=map2pix(R,x,y);
figure(4),imshow(pic);
hold on;
scatter(col,row,100,'r*');

disp(['(',num2str(x),',',num2str(y),') -> (',num2str(row),',',num2str(col),')']);
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried already.

Comment: and also a sample shapefile.... Did you try `S=shaperead('myshape.dbf')`? It will give you all the coordinates and properties of your objects and after manipulation you can write it using `shapewrite(S, 'newshape')`.

Comment: the `raster` package in R takes care of such problems

Comment: @horseshoe Thank you. If I know a contour box, can I extract this area as an normal image to process from the shape file?

Comment: @RobertH   Thank you. I will study this package.

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the earlier comment you find a piece of code below showing a simplified example of possible manipulations based on the country border file downloarable from the indicated page.

First I read in the shape than I extract the bounding box for Germany, plot it and add it to the coordinates. I use shapewrite to create the new shape, read the new shape and plot it.

In the second part I plot Germany as a polygon and save it as and image, which I then read in again and use imshow to draw it.

Does this help?

```
clear all
close all

% https://github.com/jalbertbowden/world-data/blob/master/world-borders/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.dbf
CountryShape = shaperead('TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.dbf');


countrynames{1}='Germany';
countrynames{2}='United Kingdom';
countrynames{3}='Netherlands';
countrynames{4}='France';
countrynames{5}='Belgium';
countrynames{6}='Denmark';
countrynames{7}='Norway';

figure
for i = 1:size(countrynames,2)
    xboundary = CountryShape(strcmp({CountryShape.NAME},countrynames{i})).X;
    yboundary = CountryShape(strcmp({CountryShape.NAME},countrynames{i})).Y;
    maxx = max(xboundary);
    minx = min(xboundary);
    maxy = max(yboundary);
    miny = min(yboundary);
    outerbox_x = [minx maxx maxx minx minx];
    outerbox_y = [maxy maxy miny miny maxy];

    subplot (4,2,i)
    hold on
    plot(xboundary,yboundary,'k-')
    plot(outerbox_x, outerbox_y,'r-')

    actual_id = find(strcmp({CountryShape.NAME},countrynames{i}));
    CountryShape(actual_id).X = [CountryShape(actual_id).X outerbox_x];
    CountryShape(actual_id).Y = [CountryShape(actual_id).Y outerbox_y];
end    
shapewrite(CountryShape,'newshape');
CountryShape2 = shaperead('newshape.dbf');

id_of_germany = find(strcmp({CountryShape2.NAME},'Germany'));
xboundary2 = CountryShape2(id_of_germany).X;
yboundary2 = CountryShape2(id_of_germany).Y;
subplot (4,2,i+1)
plot(xboundary2,yboundary2,'k-')

figure
fill(xboundary(~isnan(xboundary)),yboundary(~isnan(yboundary)),'r')

IM = getframe(gcf);
imwrite(IM.cdata,'myimage.png');
newIM = imread('myimage.png');
imshow(newIM)
```

Comment: Yes, this is helpful when we analysis one polygon. Any idea for not one polygon? If a box includes many polygons, is there a way?

Comment: @Shanshan: I updated the specific example so that it now does the job for several countries. If the image shall be carried out for every country just add it to the loop.

Comment: Thank you.  When we just analysis by contour, your way is very good. I would like to process just like normal image, not contour by contour. I don't think shape file can do this as far as I know. Raster is a good way.